# Find command in unix

Tags: unix, find

I want to perform a find command in a directory, and exclude from the set of results all files that are .gif, .jpeg, and .class.

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I've been trying to play with the regex option, but clearly I'm not doing it properly.

Comment: Depending on how portable you need your solution to be, `-regex` isn't part of the POSIX `find` interface.

Comment: Voting to migrate to Super User.

Comment: @dmckee: What does "Voting to migrate to Super User" mean?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to SuperUser.com than to StackOverflow.com because it is a "How do I use Foo?" question rather than a "How do I write Bar?" question. If five sufficiently high rep users (or one moderator) vote for it will be moved their automatically (locking this copy, but leaving it visible with a link so you can find the migrated one). If you have an account on SU the question will remain in your control over there, though seeing as you already have the answer you wanted that may be of modest interest to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
find . \! -name '*.class' \! -name '*.jpeg' \! -name '*.class'
```

Comment: similar:   find ./ -type f -and -not -name ".gif"  -and -not -name "*.jpeg" -and -not -name "*.class"

Comment: @AJ: Similar, yes, but personally I don't see a reason to type more and reduce portability.

Comment: @ghostdog74: If you enclose the name clauses in braces (bringing the '\!' outside) then you must use `-o` as well, e.g. `find . \! \( -name '*.class' -o -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.class' \)` otherwise the condition would not longer be correct. If that isn't what you meant I'm not sure how the `\(` and `\)` aren't redundant in this case?